# self-signed certificate issue in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-vista, https, certificate

I am setting up IIS 7.0 on a Windows Vista box. I am using self-signed certificate (by using built-in Create Self-Signed Certificate feature of IIS 7.0) on a web site. The I can browse from the local machine (the machine with IIS and web site) for the https address, for example, https://machinename/test.html, it works.

But when I browse another machine, using the same url, https://machinename/test.html, it does not work (browsers shows cannot connect error message). when browse from another machine using http, e.g. http://machinename/test.html, it works. Any ideas what is wrong? Any limitation of self-signed certificate from another machine?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Using a self-signed certificate just means the browser is going to display a warning everytime you access that page as it cannot verify the identity as the CA is not recognised.

For a quick test can you enable only SSL traffic and request HTTP from another machine and verify you get an error message?

Once you have ensured that SSL is required, can you then access over the HTTPS connection and see if you get any error message?

It would be nice if you could tell us what browser you are using as well.